# What do double superscripts mean in an ANOVA table of 'ad hoc' results

Tags: statistical-significance, anova

What is this alphabet (a,b,c) and what does its combination mean in the table?

I have read a lot of literature similar to my work and it shows that most of the researchers have used different superscript letters a, b, c, and d along with the data. It is written "the values with different superscript letters in a column are significantly different (p<0.05)"

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first row of your table, you have superscripts $c, c, d, b, b, a$ for compositions $A, B, C, D, E, F,$ respectively.

The superscripts mean that $A$ and $B$ are not
significant from each other in a statistical sense.
Also, that $D$ and $E$ are not significantly different. However, significant differences were
found between $A$ and $C,$ between $B$ and $C,$
between $E$ and $F$ (among other differences).

More generally, it is important to understand that "lack of
significant difference" is not the same thing as "exact equality".

In a similar analysis of this kind with $A$ significantly different from $C,$ you may have $B$ with an intermediate value between $A$ and $C$ and
yet not be able to decide from the data whether
to "group" $B$ with $A,$ $B$ with $C,$ or neither.
That's why some of the rows in your table have
items with double (indecisive) superscripts.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize you were still editing it!

Comment: Seems you caught the same typos I did.

Comment: How to decide where the alphabet be put first? Is it in the lowest value of mean or highest value of mean?

Comment: I don't think there is one fixed convention for this. // If letters are used, then it's usually alphabetical order from smallest to largest. // But several methods are used that don't involve superscripts. Once you know the intention is to show which means are not significantly different, it's usually easy to de-code the notation.

Answer (score 1):

Each subscript letter that is different for each parameter shows a significant difference, for example here: in the first row: there is no significant difference between A and B, nor is there a difference between D and E, but:
A and B are different from other groups, and F is different from all groups, and so on.